# How to share partition between multiple user in linux

Tags: linux

I want lebara user to access the files from the directory which mclaw user created. I have made sure that mclaw and lebara are having the same group.

```
id
uid=333(mclaw) gid=333(mclaw) groups=333(mclaw),500(lebara)
id
uid=500(lebara) gid=500(lebara) groups=500(lebara),333(mclaw)
```

I want the lebara user to access only to this directory /var/opt/anritsu/mclaw/lebara2. 
drwx------  2 mclaw  lebara    6 Mar 24 12:54 lebara2
In /home/lebara , I wish to create a soft link like ln -s /var/opt/anritsu/mclaw/lebara2 . 
However with lebara user I am never able to access lebara2 folder.

> lrwxrwxrwx  1 mclaw  mclaw    30 Mar 24 13:18 lebar ->
>   /var/opt/anritsu/mclaw/lebara2

Please guide me how this can be done. I tried getfactl and setfactl but not successful.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I completely understand your question (and the lack of formatting makes it harder) but likely the reason user `lebara` is not able to access `/var/opt/anritsu/mclaw/lebara2`, via a symlink or otherwise, shouldn't matter, is probably because that user does not have permission to traverse that entire path. Meaning: if they are not allowed to list `/var/opt/anritsu`, they will be stopped.

If you want a shared directory between two users, it may be better to put it somewhere else like `/mnt/shared` instead of a user-specific path and then verify the correct user/group/other permissions for the entire path.